# Where does the stdout from functions called by buttons go by default?

Tags: python, tkinter

The function I'm trying to call is below:

```
def numberitems(self):
    files = len(os.listdir(self.directory))
    print (items)
```

The code for the button:

```
button = Button(text = 'Count Items', command = Class1.numberItems()).pack()
```

Where I'm importing the class:

```
from class import Class1
```

Defining the directory:

```
def loadDirectory():
    return Class1(filedialog.askdirectory())
    dir = loadDirectory()
```

Comment: Where's numberOfFiles being called from?. It doesn't print out anything there, it just returns a number.

Comment: an imported class, yeah where should the number go if I havent mentioned stdout at all in the button syntax

Comment: Well *something* has to call numberOfFiles. Probably `num_files = self.numberOfFiles` or something similar. Then `print(num_files)` will print to wherever the script is directing output - typically stdout. You could even do `print(self.numberOfFiles)` to directly print without storing the data if you don't need it.

Comment: oh, so if i understand, i need to either make a function in the gui file that calls the above function but has a print statement in or just change the original function to have a print function in?

Comment: Yes. As Bryan Oakley said in his answer, the event loop doesn't know what to do with function return values - you need to tell it to print yourself. Either from within the function, or either of the two methods I exampled in my previous comment.

Comment: i have updated the code in the question, now that should print the number of files yes?

Comment: `print(files)`, no space between `print` and `(` if I'm being pedantic, but yes, that should work. You could shorten it to one line too: `print(len(os.listdir(self.directory)))`

Comment: hmm ok, its still not working. I don't think i've called the function/class in right. If i put the code for the button and where i've imported the class will you be able to have a look for me?

Comment: Yup - modify the question with your code, and I'll answer in an answer. Much longer in the comments and I'll need to move this to a chat session.

Comment: yeah thats cool, i can put more code up there if you need more to make sense of what ive done. pretty new to this so its probably all wrong

Comment: I'll need the whole python file as it's using some variables I can't see set. Also, which `chrome` package is this?  And finally: `numberOfFiles(self)` doesn't take arguments (except for `self`), yet you're passing it the result of `loadDirectory()` which won't do anything.

Comment: For context: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923764/python-why-am-i-getting-this-error-nameerror-self-is-not-defined

Comment: if you want we can go to chat and i can send you the whole files

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is not stdout. Stdout is where things go when you use the `print` statement. What you are describing is the return value of a function.

Tkinter is like all other python packages -- the return value gets returned to the caller. The caller in this situation is the event loop. The event loop doesn't know how to use the return value of functions it calls, so it throws the result away.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the context tcaswell gave, there's a couple errors in your main code.

Assuming a `chrome.py` that is:

```
class Chrome:
    directory = ""

    def __init__(self, directory):
        self.directory = directory

    def numberOfFiles(self):
        return len(os.listdir(self.directory))
```

To invoke that to print the outcome of `numberOfFiles`, you'll want to do something similar to this:

File: `q_14938600.py`

```
import os
from chrome import Chrome
from Tkinter import *

class App(object):
    """Basic TK App."""

    def __init__(self, parent):
        f = Frame(parent)
        f.pack(padx=15, pady=15)

        # Here I initiate the Chrome class, and set its directory. I'm using os.getcwd() as an example.
        self.ch = Chrome(os.getcwd())

        # Here I tell the button what to call when clicked. Note I'm NOT passing arguments to the function, just a reference.
        button = Button(f, text='Count Files', command=self.printFileCount)
        button.pack(side=BOTTOM)

    def printFileCount(self):
        # And here, I print the output of ch.numberOfFiles, which was defined in the Chrome class
        print(self.ch.numberOfFiles())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # This is just standard app stuff
    root = Tk()
    root.title('q_14938600')
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks, but i dont really get what you've done. why is the gui made as a class?

Comment: It's good practice to do so. Also, you're using `self` (Albeit in the `Chrome` class) - which generally means you have a class instance. You could do it outside of a class and it would still work, but again, it's good practice to make things like this their own class.

Comment: ok, have used pretty much what you have written just integrated it into my code now when I click the button i get an error saying that the positional argument 'self' is missing

Comment: `command=self.printFileCount` will make sure `self` is passed, have you done it any differently?

Comment: when i do it like that i get name self is not defined

Comment: would this be easier if we went into a chat?

Comment: You are doing it inside a class, yes? Note I have `def printFileCount(self)` within the App class, not outside of it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24714/discussion-between-lwh91-and-tyrantwave)